# How to perform a two part "action" in AUCTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, auctex, svg

I have been reading the pgf & tikz manual and I want too generate svg directly from my tex file. The manual says I need to run:

```
lualatex --output-format=dvi example
dvisvgm example
```

I would like to automate this process when using AUCTeX so that I can do `C-c C-c tikzsvg` to run both commands on my file. So far, I know I need to modify `TeX-command-list` to add a new AUCTeX "command". I have two issues:

1. The syntax for the command to run seems complex, with a lot of string substitution. Inspecting the variable `TeX-expand-list-builtin` is not of much help in understanding all the substitutions.
2. The procedure involves two successive commands and I am not sure how to tell auctex to run one after the other.

Can anyone provide some guidance on how to accomplish this? Is this question more suitable to emacs se?

Comment: If you don't find a suitable for you solution, keep in mind that texlive has a convert command that converts between pdf and images formats... I know it is not an answer but it may helps

Comment: Untested: Does it work if you add this to your `.emacs`, restart Emacs and do `C-c C-c` in your `.tex`file?  `(eval-after-load "tex"
  '(add-to-list 'TeX-command-list
  '("tikzsvg" "lualatex --output-format=dvi %s && dvisvgm %s" TeX-run-command t t
    :help "Run LuaLaTeX and dvisvgm") t))`

Comment: @ArashEsbati That works great. Write an answer and I'll give you the check mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an addition to `TeX-command-list` by putting something like this in your `.emacs`:

```lisp
(eval-after-load "tex"
  '(add-to-list 'TeX-command-list
                '("tikzsvg" "lualatex --output-format=dvi %s && dvisvgm %s"
                   TeX-run-command t t :help "Run LuaLaTeX and dvisvgm") t))
```

The elements of this addition are:

1. `"tikzsvg"` is the name of the command presented to you with completion when you hit <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd>
2. The second string is handed to the shell.  You can chain commands with `&&` operator
3. `%s` expands to name of the master file
4. `TeX-run-command` creates an asynchronous process with command in 2. and shows the output in a separate buffer
5. First `t` lets you modify the expanded string in Minibuffer
6. Second `t` makes this command available in every mode
7. String after `:help` is shown in the menu